# How to extract titles/text from Google Trends and print them through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, lazy-loading, webdriverwait

I would like to extract the different titles in each row from this site:

https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all

I have tried few attemps with no luck. I thought that by searching the elements by class I would get the desired text :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome('path to bin')
driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all')
hrefs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
print hrefs
print(len(hrefs))
driver.quit()
```

Thanks in advance guys!
Joan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are so close! You just need to get the text from the title, try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome('path to bin')
driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all')
Titles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('title')
for title in Titles:
    print(title.text)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB, also congrats on the `Selenium` gold tag!

Comment: about time he got it too. :-) PS: Nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

@PixelEinstein's answer will cater to your requirement just perfect. But as a part of *best practices* you should always **maximize** the *browser window* and induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elements to be visible* first then extract the text within as follows:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all')
  titles = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='title']")))
  for title in titles:
      print(title.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Mauricio Macri • Cyst • Pancreas
  Abortion • National Congress of Argentina • Debate
  Abortion • Mayra Mendoza • Argentine Chamber of Deputies • Deputy
  ```